# Is a child born to a kidnapper also considered kidnapped?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, minor-katan-child

According to Torah law if a man kidnaps a woman and has a child with her is that child now considered kidnapped as well? The question being has the man now violated the prohibition of kidnapping twice.

Comment: Why would you want to say that? There is no evidence he is holding the child against his/her will.

Comment: @gt6989b against the will of the child? The child is a minor

Comment: The child is his son/daughter. Is it possible to kidnap one's own minor child?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that is getting at the core of the question.

Comment: @nikmasi I think it's more of a distraction to the question. Why not ask about where the woman gives birth to someone else's child first?

Comment: I've been wondering about this with respect to secular law.  I figured, though, that since a father can be deemed a kidnapper if the mother has custody, then we would assume that the rapist/kidnapper never had custody of the child since she was conceived without the mother's consent.  From a halachic perspective, I think the first question is whether a rapist is recognized to have any rights of a father.

Comment: @BruceJames exactly! I believe there is ample halachic discussion of this. Does the child have obligations of kibbud av? though the kidnapping may complicate issues at it is a capital offense

Comment: See, my answer made the question boring. We don't learn about the act of the kinyan of kidnapping, that is, if you kidnap a pregnant woman and she gives birth are you now in violation again? It's because you mixed too many concepts in one question.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam writes ([Geneiva 9:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/b209.htm#5) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088876/jewish/Chapter-Nine.htm))):

> הגונב את בנו או את אחיו הקטן, וכן האפטרופין שגנבו את היתומים שהן סמוכין אצלם, ובעל הבית שגנב אחד מבני ביתו הסמוכין על שולחנו, ומלמד תינוקות שגנב אחד מן הקטנים הלומדים אצלו--אף על פי שנשתמש בו ומכרו, פטור:  שנאמר "ונמצא בידו" (שמות כא,טז), פרט לאלו שהן מצויין בידו.‏
>   The following individuals are not liable for capital punishment: a person who kidnaps his son or a brother who is below majority, a guardian who kidnaps the orphans who are in his trust, a house-owner who kidnaps one of the members of his household, and a teacher who kidnaps one of the students studying under him.
>   This applies even if the kidnapper makes use of and sells the abducted person. This is derived from the exegesis of Exodus 21:16: "And he is found in his hand." This excludes those who are constantly found in their hand. (Loose translation from Chabad)

Comment: If Dina had been raped by a Jew, rather than Shechem, would her brothers have any right to kill the rapist?  Or would they have to settle for financial damages being awarded to Jacob?

Comment: @BruceJames I'm not sure what the relevance is, but AFAIK you can kill/maim someone before they attempt to rape a girl, but afterwords you give them to the court where they get their due punishment.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even aside from נערה המאורסה ?

Comment: @Fred So...unclear. How are you supposed to know if she's betrothed?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'd be interested if you could direct me to a source for that.

Comment: @Fred I don't have one. BTW this is all theoretical because chazaka she's either a Niddah or Eshet Ish.